# Write a for loop to find a value from the active row to the end of last worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which contains 4 worksheets, each for one quarter in 2019.
I would like to write a function to check, whether the input of active cell is a duplicate from the active cell row to the end of the last worksheet.

```
Function checkDuplicate(ByVal ChangedCell As Range) As Boolean
     TelNo = ChangedCell.Value

     Range(ActiveCell.Address).Name = "StartCell"
     For i = ActiveSheet.Index To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
        Worksheets(i).Activate
        With Worksheets(i)
            Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=TelNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        End With
Next i
Application.Goto "StartCell"
If rng Is Nothing Then
    checkDuplicate = False
Else
    checkDuplicate = True
End If
```

However, it seems that it cannot even find the duplicated values in the row below the active cell.

Comment: Is 'TelNo' initialised with a value?  Have you run this through the debugger to check what it is looking for?

Comment: yes, i used MsgBox and veirfied that it could show the value

Comment: Could you add a bit more of the code? Like the initialization of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands your loop is useless. You could do this with the exact same result: `Set rng = Worksheets(4).Cells.Find(What:=TelNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)`

Try this:

```
Function checkDuplicate(ByVal ChangedCell As Range) As Boolean
  TelNo = ChangedCell.Value

  Range(ActiveCell.Address).Name = "StartCell"
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=TelNo, After:=changedCell LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
  If Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> ChangedCell.Address Then checkDuplicate = True

  If ActiveSheet.Index < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Then
     For i = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
        With Worksheets(i)
           Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:=TelNo, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
           If Not rng Is Nothing Then checkDuplicate = True
        End With
     Next i
   End If
End Function
```

Notice I added a `.` before the `range.find` call. That is for the `With Worksheets(i)` to take effect. This is also the reason why I removed the `Worksheets(i).Activate`, since it is unnecessary when fully qualifying the sheets.
Another thing to note: `Range(ActiveCell.Address).Name = "StartCell"` is implicitly called on `ActiveSheet`.

You should avoid using `ActiveSomething` in your code in general, as it can cause a great deal of errors.

Comment: it seems that it always returns true... is it because the value i am looking for is also in the same worksheet? Thanks!

Comment: i tried but it still return true whenever there is only one unique value there.... i think the logic should be correct but I have no idea where it goes wrong.

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake in my edit. Should be fixed now. The code checks for duplicates on the `ActiveSheet` after the `ChangedCell` and then loops through the following sheets and checks each one. It returns `True` after the first find, but continues with the code anyway. You could add `: Exit Function` on the line of both `If Not rng Is Nothing Then checkDuplicate = True` to exit the function right away.

Comment: @George I revised my answer again, which should solve the problem of always returning `True`. I was made aware of the fact a moment ago that `Find()` wraps around to the beginning of the range it is looking through when reaching the end of the specified range.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. Just to note you that the condition "And rng.Address <> ChangedCell.Address" should be placed in the first .find method in order to avoid checking the changedcell in the activesheet.